# The route is not working properly Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

It doesn't do me the right thing, Url changes it but the page doesn't render it.
I have two home and jobs routes, I watched doc. From Angular, but not working
This is routing.module

```
import { Route, Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NavigationJobsComponent } from './../jobs/navigation-jobs/navigation-jobs.component'
import { InputFieldComponent } from './components/input-field/input-field.component'
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: InputFieldComponent

  },{
    path: "jobs",
    component: NavigationJobsComponent
  },

];
```

This is dependency from module
`RouterModule.forRoot(routes),`

Surely someone has been hit by this before. Maybe this topic will be useful to someone, Excuse the emotions

Answer (score 2):

*"but the page doesn't render it"*

It seems like you forgot to add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your AppComponent's Template

Have created a **[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-basic-router?file=src/app/app-routing.module.ts)** for your reference

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-basic-router-7hpc7i?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-field%2Finput-field.component.ts

Comment: My URL changes but the page is not rendered

Comment: I have forked your Stackblitz demo and seems like you have missed to import the ReactiveFormsModule as you are using FormGroup. Attached is the fixed version of your stackblitz demo 

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-basic-router-f5f7fg?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: I have a question for you, how could I make the blue check-in box if my theme is black. I could ?

Comment: If it's only a matter of changing it in CSS then you could, you can follow this reference instead: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp
Hope it helps :)

Comment: Yes, I implemented this but it doesn't work, it only works 3 shades of gray I use @Treo

Answer (score 0):

As KShewengger has said above, look in your template if you're using the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. If you're using a navbar to navigate between routes, then you have to put the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your navbar Component.

If not, try to use the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your `app.component.html` (down if possible).

It would be nice if you could share your whole code about your issue, for better understand where could be it.

Comment: I still don't use Router-outlet. But I will use, The application works properly but does not render my jobs component